# What is the significance of bell in Hindiusm?

Tags: belief, temple

Bells are there in every hindu temples. There must be some significance of bells. Is there any importance of the sound of bells?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The question was not loaded in the suggestion when I was writing the question.

Comment: It is okay to have some duplicates since the original question gets some more attention:)